# Access Xero from Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to access Xero (Accounting Software) from my Google App Engine system.  (Python 2.7).

The Xero example uses M2Crypto but this uses .c files which don't seem to work on App Engine.  I also downloaded pycrypto from Google but this has the same problem.

At this stage I would just like my App Engine program to have a button for the user to log in to Xero.  Any pointers for me?

Note: Some of these packages appear to need a visual studio or a c compiler, which I don't have.

An update.  It appears that only a 'private' application needs pycrypto or m2crypto, neither of which I can install.  A public application does not need these, the example I am following has both.  I am continuing to work through this.

Thanks in advance
David (Windows Vista, Python 2.7, Current Google App Engine SDK)

Comment: In what way does Pycrypto as supplied in the appengine runtime have the same problems ?

Comment: Hi David, You've ticked the answer below, can you share an example that worked for you? Thanks.

Comment: The response below is an 'okay' guide.  I am still working through this.  The Xero examples are only bits and pieces.  Quite frustrating :)

Comment: ok - i'll be doing the same in a few days. Have you seen (https://github.com/freakboy3742/pyxero) it may be of some help...

Comment: Update - trying pyxero, as suggested by Hamish.  I can get reply from PublicCredentials() when running from Python Shell, but I get a 'TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects' error when running from my App Engine application.

Comment: Hi David, I was getting the same error, but was able to get around it by upgrading the urllib3 that is packaged as part of the requests library (requests/packages) I've included more details in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet will be to access the [Xero API Endpoints](https://community.xero.com/developer/topic/16941/) via the [AppEngine URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/).  You'll probably have to satisfy [Xero API Authentication](https://community.xero.com/developer/topic/16951/) along the way.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to access xero using pyzero, however there were a couple of gotchas, the most significant being the need to upgrade the version of urllib3 that comes packaged as part of the requests library.

I've created a simple project that demonstrates it in use.
https://github.com/hamish/gae_xero

The libraries that I needed to install were:

https://codeload.github.com/freakboy3742/pyxero/zip/master

http://labix.org/download/python-dateutil/python-dateutil-1.5.tar.gz

https://codeload.github.com/kennethreitz/requests/zip/master

https://codeload.github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/zip/master

https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/o/oauthlib/oauthlib-0.6.1.tar.gz

https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/u/urllib3/urllib3-1.7.1.tar.gz (instaled into the requests/packages/ directory)

Additionally the pycrypto library must be installed and enabled:

`sudo pip install pycrypto`

[excerpt from app.yaml]

`- name: pycrypto
  version: latest`

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Hamish.  I can see you have put quite some thought into this.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Hamish.  I can see you've thought quite a bit about this.  However, yours is a private application which uses pycrypto, while mine is public.  I can't install pycrypto because of the 'Unable to find vcvarsall.bat' error which started this whole search.  regards David.

Comment: Hi David, You are very welcome. Pyzero claims to support public applications as well a private ones. Are you still getting the too many redirects error? If so - are you still getting it after upgrading requests/packages/urllib3 ? That library is almost certainly common to both public and private apps.

Comment: fwiw - I was having similar issues but was eventually able to get things working via inspiration hamish's library, an old version of requests (2.3.0), and a minor patch to oauthlib to use the rsaalgorithm from pycrypto instead of cryptography. Happy to share a diff with anyone if useful.